# how can i set custom permission on the SharePoint groups? using rest API or PnP- js

Tags: sharepoint-online

i want to break the inheritance permission on the group and want to set custom permission. is it possible?

please help me i am new in SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change permission on an item (I'm quite puzzled that you mention permission on a group) it can be done using the following endpoints:

Break inheritance:
`/_api/web/lists(guid'#1')/items(#2)/breakroleinheritance(true)` (#1 being the guid of the list and #2 being the id of the item you wish to break inheritance)

Remove permissions of a user/group: `/_api/web/lists(guid'#1')/items(#2)/roleassignments(#3)` (#1 being the guid of the list, #2 being the id of the item you wish to break inheritance and #3 being the principal id of the user). This must be called with a x-http-metod = DELETE in the header.

Add permission of a user/group:
`/_api/web/lists(guid'#1')/items(#2)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=#3,roleDefId=#4)`(#1 being the guid of the list, #2 being the id of the item you wish to break inheritance, #3 being the principal id of the user and #4 being the role definition id of the permission you want to grant)